# Android room library Migration change type of previous column

Tags: android, database, migration

I am using room library to handle database part in my android app. I want to migrate from my db version 3 to 4. I have added two new columns in my table while migration. But while migration, it change type of date_time column from TEXT to DATETIME.I am getting following exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle table_transactions(com.example.braintech.demosmspickerapp.database.TransactionModel).
    Expected:
    TableInfo{name='table_transactions', columns={entry_type=Column{name='entry_type', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, dg=Column{name='dg', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, balance=Column{name='balance', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, date=Column{name='date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, date_time=Column{name='date_time', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, reading_grid=Column{name='reading_grid', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, note=Column{name='note', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
    Found:
    TableInfo{name='table_transactions', columns={entry_type=Column{name='entry_type', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, dg=Column{name='dg', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, balance=Column{name='balance', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, date=Column{name='date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, date_time=Column{name='date_time', type='DATETIME', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, reading_grid=Column{name='reading_grid', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, note=Column{name='note', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = AppConstants.TABLE_TRANSACTIONS)
public class TransactionModel implements Serializable {


    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    public String date;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "balance")
    public String balance;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "reading_grid")
    public String reading_grid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dg")
    public String dg;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_time")
    public String date_time;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note")
    public String note;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "entry_type")
    public String entry_type;

    @Ignore
    Date dateForCompare;
}
```

Migration Code

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {


        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE '" + AppConstants.TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + "' ADD COLUMN 'note' TEXT ");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE '" + AppConstants.TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + "' ADD COLUMN 'entry_type' TEXT ");
        Log.d("VROM", "Migration");
    }
};
```

Comment: It is saying your existing table (the 'found' table in your database) is using `DATETIME`, but your Room definition has `date_time` as a String, hence the `TEXT` expected type. Was version 3 not generated by Room?

Comment: no version 3 was generated by simple Database open helper class

Comment: Your migration needs to handle every difference - `DATETIME` isn't a supported column type for a `String` field in Room, so you need to convert it over to the required type.

Comment: how can I convert it

Answer (score 0):

In your exception I saw to differences, the first one is:

```
Expected: id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}

Found: id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}
```

Changed from `notNull=true` to `notNull=false`

and the second one is:

```
Expected: date_time=Column{name='date_time', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}

Found: date_time=Column{name='date_time', type='DATETIME', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}
```

Changed from `type='TEXT', affinity='2'` to `type='DATETIME', affinity='1'`

So, could you try to add `@NonNull` annotation on primary keys and try to migrate again?

Comment: So I need to change db version again

Comment: what is affinity?